# Filter array of objects against another array of objects. Remove items with array values that matches those inside another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, foreach

I've used `.filter` successfully in the past, but I can't figure out this use case.

I want to return a clone of the array `chordLibrary` (presumably using `.filter`). But I want to remove any items/objects from this new array where any array value of the property name `notesInChord` happens to match any of the array values of `badNotes.keyIndex`.

To clarify, I will compare each item in `chordLibrary` against every item in `badNotes` and remove an item from `chordLibrary` if its array values matches any of the array values in any of the items items in `badNotes`.

In the following example, you can see that the first item in `chordLibrary` includes the array value `5`, and so that item is removed in the result.

```
const chordLibrary = [
    { notesInChord: [5, 8], chordName: 'Major' },
    { notesInChord: [4, 8], chordName: 'Minor' },
    { notesInChord: [8], chordName: '5' }
];
const badNotes = [
    {"keyIndex":[1],"keyName":"C#"},
    {"keyIndex":[3],"keyName":"D#"},
    {"keyIndex":[5],"keyName":"E"}
];

// example result: "
const newChordLibrary = [
    { notesInChord: [4, 8], chordName: 'Minor' },
    { notesInChord: [8], chordName: '5' }
];
```

I assume I need to nest or use a for loop or forEach to do this, but I can't figure it out.

ES6 solutions are ok.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `filter` you can use a custom method that searches in the `notesInChord` if any of them are found in badNotes using `find` as follows:

```js
const chordLibrary = [
    { notesInChord: [5, 8], chordName: 'Major' },
    { notesInChord: [4, 8], chordName: 'Minor' },
    { notesInChord: [8], chordName: '5' }
];
const badNotes = [
    {"keyIndex":[1],"keyName":"C#"},
    {"keyIndex":[3],"keyName":"D#"},
    {"keyIndex":[5],"keyName":"E"}
];

function getGoodNotes(chordList){
     return chordList.filter((chord)=>{
          if(!containsBadNote(chord.notesInChord))
               return chord;
     });
}
function containsBadNote(notesInChord){
     for(let i = 0; i < notesInChord.length; i++){
          var note = notesInChord[i];
          if(badNotes.find((n)=> n.keyIndex[0]==note)!=null)
               return true;
     }
     return false;
}

console.log( getGoodNotes(chordLibrary) );
```

Comment: Great! This seems to work! I'll look a little closer and then Accept.